# Java String Comparison using Recursion

Tags: java, string, recursion, comparison

This is a homework assignment where I have to compare two strings from command line
arguments, convert both of them to their lowercase versions, perform
comparison and print out the string that precedes/is smaller than the other string
in the dictionary order. The strings can have any arbitrary lengths.

however, my algorithm MUST USE RECURSION.

I'm not sure if 1 - i am using recursions, or 2- why it doesn't work for Hello and Hallo but does for Homework and homePhOne.

please help!!!

```
 import java.util.Scanner;


public class MyStringCompare
 {  
 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input String 1");
String x = in.next();
String xl = toLowerCase(x);
System.out.println("Input String 2");
String y = in.next();
String yl = toLowerCase(y);


char a = xl.charAt(0);
char b = yl.charAt(0);
int min = 0;

if (a < b)
{

  System.out.println("The smallest string is " +xl);
}
if (a > b)
{

  System.out.println("The smallest string is " +yl);
}
else if (a == b)
{
  min = toCompare(xl,yl);
  if (min == -1)
  {
  System.out.println("The smallest string is " +xl);
  }
  if (min == 1)
        {
    System.out.println("The smallest string is " +yl);
  }
  else if (min == 0)
  {
    System.out.println("Two strings are equal");
  }
}



}



 public static String toLowerCase( String s )
{
   String output;
   output = "";
   int i;
   char a;
   char b;


   for (i = 0; i<s.length(); i++)
   {
     a = s.charAt(i);


     if (a >= 65 && a <= 90)
     {
         b = (char)( a+32);
        output = output + b; 
        }
        else
        {

                output = output + a; 

        }
    }

   return output;
   }


    public static int toCompare (String m, String n)
    {
   int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int min = 0;
 for (i = 0; i< m.length(); i++)
 {

   for (j = 0; j < n.length(); j++)
   {
     char a = m.charAt(i);

     char b = n.charAt(j);


     if (a < b)
     {
       min = -1;

     }
     if (a > b)
     {
       min = 1; 

     }
     else if (a == b)
     {

       min = 0;

     }

     }
   }





return min;
}






 }
```

Comment: You are not using recursion in the code sample.

Comment: To use recursion, your method has to call itself or call a method that in turn calls it.

Comment: I thought I was using recursion during the first else if (a == b) and then I call the toCompare method

Comment: Also, it does not actually work for any strings... but it behaves differently when the first characters are different.  Namely if they are different the method `toCompare()` is never called.  I think maybe it is time to go back to the design phase, and try writing this again.

Answer (score 0):

define a static boolean variable flag = false in the class declaration,
define all the strings as static global varibles,so that you dont have to use the pass them to the recursive method.

call the compare(0) from main
use this recursion procedure :

```
private static void compare(int i)
{  
   if(x1.length()!=x2.length())
   {
       flag =false; return;
   }
   else
   {
   if((i<x1.length())&&(i<x2.length()))
  {
   if(x1.charAt(i)==x2.charAt(i))
   {
    i++;compare(i);flag =true;
   }
   else
   flag =false; return;
  }}
}
```

check if the flag is true to see if the strings are equal by each character.
Here is my version of the program using recursion.

```
import java.util.*;

public class sol {

static String x1;
static String x2;
static boolean flag=false;
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    x1= (in.nextLine());
    x1=x1.toLowerCase();
    x2= (in.nextLine());
    x2=x2.toLowerCase();
    compare(0);in.close();
    if(flag==true)
        System.out.print("Strings are equal");
    else
        System.out.print("Strings are not equal");
}
private static void compare(int i)
{  
   if(x1.length()!=x2.length())
   {
       flag =false; return;
   }
   else
   {
   if((i<x1.length())&&(i<x2.length()))
  {
   if(x1.charAt(i)==x2.charAt(i))
   {
    i++;compare(i);flag =true;
   }
   else
   flag =false; return;
  }}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when doing a recursive method:

- Study **which params your may need**:

  -m: String to compare

  -n: String to compare
- Which **base case** do you need?
  This means, when shall your method stop calling himself?
  In this case, when no more characters left to be compared.
- **Call recursively your method**:
  You call the method comparing from left to right. 
  For instance: hello hallo

  ```
  (1)compare hello hallo 

   (2)will call-> compare ello allo

    (3)which will call-> compare llo llo

     (4)which will call-> lo lo

      (5)which will call-> o o

       (6)which will call-> '' '' 

         which wont call more himself: no more characters left to be compared->basecase!
  ```
- But **collecting the returned value**, you will be going from right to left

  ```
       (6)compare '' '' will return true

      (5)compare 'o' 'o' will return (the result of 6)true && true ('o'=='o')  ->true

     (4)compare 'lo' 'lo' will return (5)true && true ('l'=='l')   ->true

    (3)compare 'llo' 'llo' will return (4)true && true ('l' == 'l')   ->true

   (2)compare 'ello' 'allo' will return (3)true && false ('e' != 'a')   ->false

  (1)compare 'hello' 'hallo' will return (2)false && true ('h' == 'h')   ->false
  ```